# Inspect a given route to determine if it has a subdomain constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, url-helper

I'm building a Rails app that has a `merchant` subdomain. I have these two routes:

```
get '/about', controller: :marketing, action: :about, as: :about
get '/about', controller: :merchant, action: :about, constraints: { subdomain: 'merchant' }, as: :merchant_about
```

But when I use their URL helpers both `merchant_about_url` and `about_url` result in `http://example.com/about`.

I know I can specify the `subdomain` argument on the helper to prefix the URL with the subdomain, but since these URLs are going to be frequently used in various cases I'd like to build a wrapper for this helper to make it smarter.

**My question: Can I inspect a given route to see if it has a subdomain constraint?**

If I can, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
def smart_url(route_name, opts={})
  if # route_name has subdomain constraint
    opts.merge!({ subdomain: 'merchant' })
  end

  send("#{route_name}_url", opts)
end
```

In doing this, I can effectively call:

```
smart_url('about')          # http://example.com/about
smart_url('merchant_about') # http://merchant.example.com/about
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I inspect a given route to see if it has a subdomain constraint?

Yes, that is possible. You need to use Rails' routes API to get info about the route.

```
def smart_url(route_name, opts={})
  route = Rails.application.routes.routes.detect {|r| r.name == route_name }

  if opts.is_a? Hash && route&.constraints[:subdomain]
    opts.merge!({ subdomain: 'merchant' })
  end

  send("#{route_name}_url", opts)
end
```

The above searches a route by its name, and inspects its constraints if the route is found.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much :) If you have a minute, I'm running in to one issue where `opts` can be an AR model instead of a hash. For example, `user_url(@user)` (`smart_url('user', @user)`). I can't append the `subdomain` argument to this. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JodyHeavener -- Please check my updated answer. You can manually typecheck for such situations.

Answer (score -1):

you can create class under lib folder like this

```
class Subdomain
    def self.matches?(request)
        case request.subdomain
        when SUB_DOMAIN_NAME
          true
        else
          false
        end
    end
end
```

and in your routes.rb file create routes like this

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
    get '/about', to: 'marketings#about', as: :about
end

get '/about', to: 'marketings#about', as: :merchant_about
```